# altering the clustered index in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I alter the clustered index on PK to change the index column or include extra column?

Do I drop and create using the [create index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-clustered-indexes)?

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX dateQ ON dbo.devTable(DateCreated, Id)
```

Clicking `drop and create` on SSMS spit the following. I have no idea what's going on inside the `with` parameters. I want to include the `datecreated` to my index.

```
USE [devDb]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[devTable] DROP CONSTRAINT 
[PK__devTab__3214EC07339391EF] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[devTable] ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [DateCreated] ASC, //I want to add date created to the index
 [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = 
ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: If you want to add a column to an index, then yes, you need to drop and recreate the index. Considering, however, that this is also a primary key, you'll need to drop any referencing foreign keys as well first, then drop the Primary Key, and then re-add your foreign keys. Generally, however, it's a bad idea to use 2 columns as your Primary key. I'd also recommend giving your PK a name, rather than having it being given an automatically generated one.

Comment: I want to index my items in ascending create date. What could be the best way to go about that?

Comment: What's wrong with the query you have?

Comment: @Larnu I was referring to your statement that says it's bad idea to use 2 columns as primary key. I thought creating a combined index of identity with datecreated would be the way to go.

Comment: But you're not just creating an index, you're creating a `PRIMARY KEY` on 2 fields. There's nothing wrong with having an index containing multiple columns, in fact it's normally what you do. What you don't generally want to to is create a `PRIMARY KEY` that has multiple columns as you should have at least one column that is unique already.

Comment: oh. sorry for me being the noob on db things. My intention is to create a clustered index on date and the id not create primary key on those 2 fields. So I guess I'm totally not on the right track here. Have any idea on how to go about that?

Comment: @legen---waitforit---dary, to make sure you are aware, a clustered index on DateCreated will not guarantee ascending order in query results unless you specify `ORDER BY DateCreated`. The index may help improve efficiency of those queries, though.

Comment: Hi @DanGuzman I'll be doing mostly `... where DateCreated between ..., select min or max(DateCreated)` queries.

Comment: @legen---waitforit---dary, yes, the clustered index will help performance of those queries. Since you mentioned you are a noob, I just wanted to make sure you understood that an `ORDER BY' clause is required if you need rows are returned in a particular sequence regardless of the clustered index.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks... yeah. I'm a noob at work.LOL! I've been doing some research recently. I didn't even know how indexing work(and still don't, just that every guru says it helps with query perfomance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the below sample script should help you out.

```
USE Sandbox;
GO
--Very simple sample table
CREATE TABLE IndexSample (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                          DateCreated date,
                          CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID ASC));
GO

--You can only have one CLUSTERED INDEX on a table. As you've declared the ID as CLUSTERED PRIMARY KEY you'll need to drop it
--Note that if this key is referenced anywhere eklse, you'll need to drop those keys as well.
ALTER TABLE IndexSample DROP CONSTRAINT PK_ID;

GO
--Now, we need to recreate the PRIMARY KEY, but not CLUSTER it.
ALTER TABLE IndexSample ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (ID ASC);
--Then create your other Foreign keys and constraints again
GO
--Now create your Clsutered index
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX DateCreated_ID ON IndexSample (DateCreated ASC, ID ASC);

GO
--Clean up
DROP TABLE IndexSample;
```

As I note in my comments, you'll need to `DROP` your existing constraint, as you can't "uncluster" an `INDEX`. Once you've dropped it, you can then create a new `NONCLUSTERED` `PRIMARY KEY`. Finally, you then add your new `CLUSTERED` index.